# angularjs difference between $eval and dot access

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1. `$scope.$parent.$parent.GoodsVal.GoodsItem.MinOrderUnit`
2. `$scope.$eval('$parent.$parent.GoodsVal.GoodsItem.MinOrderUnit')`

What is different 1 and 2?

I think 1 is better.

Comment: Neither is good...use a service anytime you start doing things like `$parent.$parent`

Comment: @charlietfl Can you explain in detail?